# How to create a variable from a list containing string elements in R?

Tags: r, string, for-loop

I've a list of fruits, which are string elements:

```
fruits_list <- c("apple", "banana", "cantaloupe")
```

I'd like to create variables from this list of string elements:

```
for (i 1:3){ 
                 paste(fruits_list[i], collapse = "")[i] <- rnorm(1)
           }
```

How can I achieve this? Furthermore, I didn't allocate an empty vector before the for loop, because I don't know the syntax. Thank you in advance.

My expected output is the following:

```
apple = [4.297527 2.536948 2.002569] 
banana = [3.106884 2.465443 2.107154] 
cantaloupe = [2.642232 1.990945 1.496947]
```

Comment: Do you want to create new variables inside an existing dataframe, or a new object for each fruit?

Comment: Please add your expected output.

Comment: `list2env(as.list(sapply(fruits_list, function(x) x = rnorm(1))), envir = .GlobalEnv)` puts three new objects named after the fruits, each a numeric scalar, in your global environment.

Comment: @LAP Wouldn't `lapply` be better than `as.list(sapply(.))`?

Comment: `invisible(lapply(fruits_list,function(x){assign(x,rnorm(1),envir = .GlobalEnv)}))` ???

Comment: `"names<-"(data.frame(lapply(fruits_list, function(i) i <- rnorm(1))), fruits_list)` produces a data frame with your variables.

Comment: @RuiBarradas no because lapply does not make "names". What LAP can do is to set `simplify = F`.

Comment: @AndreElrico Right, the `as.list()` could be avoided.

Comment: @AndreElrico Right, I forgot about the names.

Comment: Cleaner to just use a vector - `setNames(rnorm(length(fruits_list)), fruits_list)`

Comment: I added the expected output. Thank you for the comments.

Comment: Where did the numbers in your expected output come from? Also, wouldn't a dataframe be better than 3 different variables?

Comment: rnorm() function

Comment: Those specific numbers don't look like the output of `rnorm`.

Comment: @JohnColeman Updated.